# Get element by its attribute value?

Tags: java, xml, libgdx

Is it possible to select/get an element by its attribute value? So in my example below, can I select one of the elements based on the name attribute using the LibGDX XmlReader?

```
<root>
  <element name="foo"/>
  <element name="bar"/>
</root>
```

To clarify, I want to access the element directly if that is even possible. Not like below:

```
for (XmlReader.Element e : root.getChildrenByName("element")
{
    if (e.getAttribute("name").Equals("foo"))
    {
        //Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Reason for this is my coding flow first needs to work one element, then do more stuff independently of this element/xml. Then when done I need to get another element so I need to iterate over many elements again and repeat that until done. I wish I had more control over the produced XML files so I could just give them their own element name; these XML files are a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getChildrenByName()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.Element.html#getChildrenByName%28java.lang.String%29) for this one.

Comment: That creates an array of the elements and i have to check on every elements name myself right? It does not directly pick a correct element or does it? It goes like this: root.getChildrenByName("element").

Comment: Yes.. you can use the enhanced for loop, `for (XmlReader.Element target : elements.getChildrenByName("element")) {
    // this should be iterated three times, once for each target
}`

Comment: Yeah, figured that one out already. Just don't want to loop everything in my XML. I want to work on a certain element do some more stuff and then go to the next element where i have to loop them all again. Anyway, if directly selecting them is not possible I try to change my flow and work all these elements first inside the loop. Wish i had some more control over the XML file, it's a nightmare :).